# How Do I Link an object file from multiple other object files in cmake?

Tags: cmake, linker

I have a list of OBJECT libraries, I want to link them into a single object '.o' file, so that I can control their visibility. I know that object files can linked from other object files on Linux like so

```
ld -r -o foo-combined.o foo1.o foo2.o
```

I want to do this with OBJECT libraries in my cmake project into a single OBJECT

Comment: CMake won't make it easy to do that. The closest thing would be a static library, but that's probably not what you want. You could use `add_custom_command`, but that will mess with the way CMake treats the resulting file so it may not be easy to link it into other targets

Comment: You might consider a different approach. For example, if you want to control visibility of specific symbols, you can use `target_compile_options` to add visibility flags. There's also a `-X` linker command that I think might strip out the object file names from the symbol table (you should double-check me on that)